# nextAuth.js accessToken is undefined. all i get is {iat, exp, jti}

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

This is my code:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export default NextAuth({
  sectret:process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
        name: 'Credentials',
        type: 'credentials',
        credentials: {},
       
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            });
            const resJson = await res.json();
            const user = resJson.user;
            if (user) {
              return user;
            } else {
              return null;
            }
            
            
            
    }
})
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account}) {
      console.log(account)
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token;
  
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  }
})
```

I have tried a lot of things i have seen in other peoples code, but I cannot seem to get the accessToken, I am using next.js latest

the response I get after login is
{iat: 4234234, exp: 23423423424, jti: 'sefsefsfesfsefs'}
instead of the token
Do you know how should I procceed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.
You need to pass the 'account' as a parameter in your callback function.

```
....
async function jwt({ token, user, account }) {
  return { ...token, ...user, ...account };
}
```

Now, you have all the data that you received as a return from the API call.